# Can not running the JavaFX with command in Window Terminal

Tags: java

I can not run my JavaFX application with cmd :

```
java --module-path "C:\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml App
```

But when i press run with Java Code Runner extensions and it's actually working.

Someone explain me why? Thanks <3

You can see in my 2 pics down below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyCqW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxuD6.png)

Comment: Probably your default Java runtime is not compatible with Java modules. What do you get if you type `java -version` in terminal ? Look at the output when you run from VC, it is using a full path to a Java runtime.

Comment: Please include the errors in textual format rather than image links.